# Passing filter as an angular directive param

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters

I would like to pass w filter as a param to a custom directive in my app. I would like to do something like:

Usage in application:

```
<my-directive data='dataVariable' dataFilter='numericFilter: 123'/>
```

Directive template:

```
<span> {{ data | dataFilter }} </span>
```

Directive:

```
...
scope: {
  data: '=',
  dataFilter: '@'
}
...
```

When I do it as shwon above I get error related to syntax (`:` is not recognized), dependency injection (filter is not found) or the filter simply does nothing.

Comment: Your `dataFilter` attribute should be `data-filter`. And how does `dataFilter` attribute work within the directive? Show the contents of your `my-directive`

Comment: `dataFilter` is not used inside the directive code. It is only needed to format HTML output.

Answer (score 6):

You can dynamically get the filter you want by using the filter service:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDir', ['$filter', function($filter) { 
....
     link: function($scope, $el, $attr) {
          var desiredFilter = $filter($attr['dataFilter']);
         //desiredFilter is now a function that will run the filter passed, it will throw exception if filter is not found
      }
 }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could build up your expression in your compile function based off of your attributes.
However, I would recommend using $filter as suggested by @PinhasHouri.

http://plnkr.co/edit/B3UM4CMTQ1BjTR2zK7IP?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div apply-filter 
         filter-data="Hello" 
         filter-expr="append:'C'"></div>

    <script>
      var app  = angular.module("app",[]);

      app.directive("applyFilter",function(){
        return{
          filterExpr: "@",
          filterData: "@",
          compile: function(element,attrs){
            element.append("{{'" + attrs.filterData + "'|" +  attrs.filterExpr + "}}");
          }
        }
      });

      app.filter("append",function(){
        return function(v,p){
          return v + p;
        }
      });

      angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```